# Rewrite rule works on Apache but not on Lighthttpd

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, lighttpd

I have some rewrite rules in .htaccess (placed in same folder as PHP files) on my Apache server:

```
RewriteRule ^sensor/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ api_sensor.php?param=$1 [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^sensor/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ api_sensor.php?param=$1&zone=$2 [NC,L]
```

It works OK - when I navigate to `localhost/rest/sensor/Foo/Bar` it rewrites to `localhost/rest/api_sensor.php?param=Foo&Zone=Bar`

But target server is running lighttpd which doesn't support .htaccess file, so I rewrite rules to supported syntax and placed them into /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf:

```
url.rewrite-once = ( 
    "^/rest/sensor/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$" => "/rest/api_sensor.php?param=$1",
    "^/rest/sensor/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$"  => "/rest/api_sensor.php?param=$1&zone=$2"
)
```

When I navigate to the same url as before, it returns *404 Page not found*. Where is the problem? Rewriting with simple rules (without regexs etc.) works OK.

Answer (score 0):

Solved myself. I had to replace `([a-z0-9\-]+)` with `([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)`, then it works. I forgot that NC flag in .htaccess RewriteRule makes it case-unsensitive.